# Connect to specific Database with sqlalchemy + Pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have numerous databases on a server,I am able to connect using :
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@some_dsn"). However, this  connects to the default database. Is there a way i can specify a particular Database on the server? I tried :engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@some_dsn/bdname") but this did not work

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server):

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname')
```

Comment: thanks Tiny. but your solution is via pymssql is there no way to do this with pyodbc?

Comment: Hi Tiny, please what would the host name and port be when using pymssql? i am failry new to this.many thanks

Comment: the host name is the db's host ( server name where your db is hosted), you can try with this link to check your port number https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2495/identify-sql-server-tcp-ip-port-being-used/